# How do I make a Jbutton in a GUI open a new GUI window?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouselistener

We are making a Bananagrams game. We want to use a mouseListener (which we can't figure out how to write) to click on a JButton, which will in turn open a new window in GUI. How can we do this?

Code: This is my code for Bananagramz!!!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   //private JPanel pane;
    private Container  pane; 
    private JButton start;
    private JRadioButton five, fifteen, ten;
    private JLabel welcome,instructions, ins, inst, instr;
    private int i;
    public Gui() {
        this.setTitle("BANANAGRAMZ");
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setLocation(100,100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pane = this.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    five = new JRadioButton("Check here if you want 5 minutes to play!");
    ten = new JRadioButton("Check here if you want 10  minutes to play!");  
    fifteen = new JRadioButton("Check here if you want 15 minutes to play!");

    welcome = new JLabel("Welcome to Bananagramz!");
    instructions = new JLabel("You will be given 50 tiles randomly chosen from a pot of 144.");
    ins = new JLabel ("Your goal is to make a grid of (real) English words,");
    inst = new JLabel ("which will be checked (for realness) at the end, within a time limit.");
    instr = new JLabel("Think hard, and beat the clock!");
    JButton start = new JButton("Go!");

     pane.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
     pane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    pane.add(welcome);
    pane.add(five);
    pane.add(ten);
    pane.add(fifteen);


    pane.add(instructions);
    pane.add(ins);
    pane.add(inst);
    pane.add(instr);

    pane.add(start);
    }
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("mouse cliekd");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui g = new Gui();
        g.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at any of the tutorials provided by Oracle? Check them out [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: I've tried everything on Oracle; i can't make any actionListener do anything at all!

Comment: @magz show us your code.

Comment: Like JJPA says, if you post the code you have written we can adjust it for you to point out flaws and where you went wrong, maybe even solve your problem for you.

Comment: public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Comment: Please post your code as an edit to your question, not in a comment since you can't format code in a comment. Please let's see a serious attempt. Also, don't use a MouseListener on a JButton, but rather use an ActionListener as I'm sure you've seen that the tutorial already tells you to do.

Comment: Please re-read my last comment. Again, don't post code in a comment, but as an edit to your question. Again, do *not* use a MouseListener on a JButton but rather use an ActionListener. Again, please post a serious attempt. If your code does not compile, show error messages. If it throws an exception, then post the exception stack trace.

Comment: We really are trying to help you here magz.

Comment: It compiles fine; I added my code as an edit

Comment: OK, thanks for the code. Now where exactly are you stuck? Where's your attempt to open a window? All your ActionListener does is increment an int. But you've yet to add your ActionListener to a button. Have you gone through the button tutorials?

Comment: Well it does even print out the incremented int, so I didnt want to move on from there. The final goal is to open a window. Yes I've gone through the button tutorials

Comment: Then where do you add the ActionListener to your button? Here's the link again: [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Comment: That's what I can't figure out

Comment: Thank you everyone!!! I have finally made some progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems as I saw is you declared

```
private JButton start;
```

but in your constructor you did

```
JButton start = new JButton("Go!");
```

it should be

```
start = new JButton("Go!");
```

and register a listener to the button like below

```
start.addActionListener(this);
```